# Script is not glob-expanding, but works fine when running the culprit as a minimalistic example

Tags: bash

I've been trying for hours on this problem, and cannot set it straight.

This minimal script works *as* *it* *should*:

```
#!/bin/bash
wipe_thumbs=1

if (( wipe_thumbs )); then
 src_dir=$1
 thumbs="$src_dir"/*/t1*.jpg
 echo $thumbs
fi
```

Invoke with `./script workdir` and a lot of filenames starting with t1* in all the sub-dirs of `workdir` are shown.

When putting the above if-case in the bigger script, the globbing is not executed:

```
SRC: -- workdir/ --
THUMBS: -- workdir//*/t1*.jpg --
ls: cannot access workdir//*/t1*.jpg: No such file or directory
```

The only difference with the big script and the minimal script is that the big script has a path-validator and getopts-extractor. This code is immediately above the if-case:

```
#!/bin/bash
OPTIONS=":ts:d:"
src_dir=""
dest_dir=""
wipe_thumbs=0

while getopts $OPTIONS opt ; do
  case "$opt" in
    t) wipe_thumbs=1
       ;;
  esac
done
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

src_dir="$1"
dest_dir="${2:-${src_dir%/*}.WORK}"

# Validate source
echo -n "Validating source..."
if [[ -z "$src_dir" ]]; then
  echo "Can't do anything without a source-dir."
  exit
else
  if [[ ! -d "$src_dir" ]]; then
    echo "\"$src_dir\" is really not a directory."
    exit
  fi
fi
echo "done"

# Validate dest
echo -n "Validating destination..."
if [[ ! -d "$dest_dir" ]]; then
  mkdir "$dest_dir"
  (( $? > 0 )) && exit
else
  if [[ ! -w "$dest_dir" ]]; then
    echo "Can't write into the specified destination-dir."
    exit
  fi
fi
echo "done"


# Move out the files into extension-named directories
echo -n "Moving files..."

if (( wipe_thumbs )); then
  thumbs="$src_dir"/*/t1*.jpg               # not expanded
  echo DEBUG THUMBS: -- "$thumbs" --
  n_thumbs=$(ls "$thumbs" | wc -l)
  rm "$thumbs"
fi

...rest of script, never reached due to error...
```

Can anyone shed some lights on this? Why is the glob not expanded in the big script, but working fine in the minimalistic test script?

**EDIT**: Added the complete if-case.

Comment: Are you sure the working directory is the same? How do you invoke the bigger script? Have you tried commenting parts of your bigger script until it works again?

Comment: Yes, working dir is the same. Big and small script reside in the same directory - as does the workdir - and are invoked in the same way. Small works fine, big does not. Have not tried commenting out, will do so now.

Comment: What's in the "... rest of script ..." part? Most importantly, what's the exact `ls` command that's causing the error, and is the reference to `$thumbs` in double-quotes or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that wildcards aren't expanded in assignment statements (e.g. `thumbs="$src_dir"/*/t1*.jpg`), but are expanded when variables are used without double-quotes. Here's an interactive example:

```
$ src_dir=workdir
$ thumbs="$src_dir"/*/t1*.jpg
$ echo $thumbs    # No double-quotes, wildcards will be expanded
workdir/sub1/t1-1.jpg workdir/sub1/t1-2.jpg workdir/sub2/t1-1.jpg workdir/sub2/t1-2.jpg
$ echo "$thumbs"    # Double-quotes, wildcards printed literally
workdir/*/t1*.jpg
$ ls $thumbs    # No double-quotes, wildcards will be expanded
workdir/sub1/t1-1.jpg   workdir/sub2/t1-1.jpg
workdir/sub1/t1-2.jpg   workdir/sub2/t1-2.jpg
$ ls "$thumbs"    # Double-quotes, wildcards treated as literal parts of filename
ls: workdir/*/t1*.jpg: No such file or directory
```

...so the quick-n-easy fix is to remove the double-quotes from the `ls` and `rm` commands. But this isn't safe, as it'll also cause parsing problems if `$src_dir` contains any whitespace or wildcard characters (this may not be an issue for you, but I'm used to OS X where spaces in filenames are *everywhere*, and I've learned to be careful about these things). The best way to do this is to store the list of thumb files as an array:

```
$ src="work dir"
$ thumbs=("$src_dir"/*/t1*.jpg)    # No double-quotes protect $src_dir, but not the wildcard portions
$ echo "${thumbs[@]}"    # The "${array[@]}" idiom expands each array element as a separate word
work dir/sub1/t1-1.jpg work dir/sub1/t1-2.jpg work dir/sub2/t1-1.jpg work dir/sub2/t1-2.jpg
$ ls "${thumbs[@]}"
work dir/sub1/t1-1.jpg  work dir/sub2/t1-1.jpg
work dir/sub1/t1-2.jpg  work dir/sub2/t1-2.jpg
```

You might also want to set nullglob in case there aren't any matches (so it'll expand to a zero-length array).

In your script, this'd come out something like this:

```
if (( wipe_thumbs )); then
  shopt -s nullglob
  thumbs=("$src_dir"/*/t1*.jpg)              # expanded as array elements
  shopt -u nullglob    # back to "normal" to avoid unexpected behavior later
  printf 'DEBUG THUMBS: --'
  printf ' "%s"' "${thumbs[@]}"
  printf ' --\n'
  # n_thumbs=$(ls "${thumbs[@]}" | wc -l)    # wrong way to do this...
  n_thumbs=${#thumbs[@]}    # better...
  if (( n_thumbs == 0 )); then
    echo "No thumb files found" >&2
    exit
  fi
  rm "${thumbs[@]}"
fi
```